# Bricked Mega2560 - avrdude gets only zeroes

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, atmel, avrdude

On a Creality CR-X 3D printer (mainboard based on Atmel Mega2560-16u), an upgrade of the firmware had first failed before end when uploaded by Cura slicer via USB. After the fail, the printer became unresponsive, and it was impossible to upload again from Cura or from Arduino IDE and USB.

I deduced that the bootloader might have been corrupted and needed to be re-uploaded. That upload was not possible from Arduino IDE using `Mega2560` Board / `Arduino as ISP` / `Burn bootloader` because of `invalid device signature`. 
I tried from command line to be able to override the signature check with `-F`.

Example of a failing booloader uplod:

```
avrdude -p m2560 -c avrisp -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 19200 -U flash:w:Arduino-COMBINED-dfu-usbserial-atmega16u2-Mega2560-Rev3.hex -U lfuse:w:0xFF:m -U hfuse:w:0xD8:m -U efuse:w:0xFD:m -U lock:w:0x0F:m -vv
```

I am unsure of the result of the upload from Arduino IDE, but the command contains the `-e` switch to erase the chip and now each time I try to get some values, or upload a binary to `flash` or `fuse` the verification gets only zeroes. Prior to the failed flash I did manage to make a dump of the flash to backup the factory firmware.

I have also a chinese UsbAsp and a BusPirate 3.6, but none of them seem to communicate with the Mega2560.

Did I definitely bricked my board?

Example of read:

````
avrdude -p m2560 -c avrisp -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 19200 -U lfuse:r:-:h -U hfuse:r:-:h -v

avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/seki/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyACM0
         Using Programmer              : avrisp
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 19200
         AVR Part                      : ATmega2560
         Chip Erase delay              : 9000 us
         PAGEL                         : PD7
         BS2                           : PA0
         RESET disposition             : dedicated
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    10     8    0 no       4096    8      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           flash         65    10   256    0 yes    262144  256   1024  4500  4500 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : STK500
         Description     : Atmel AVR ISP
         Hardware Version: 2
         Firmware Version: 1.18
         Topcard         : Unknown
         Vtarget         : 0.0 V
         Varef           : 0.0 V
         Oscillator      : Off
         SCK period      : 0.1 us

avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000 (retrying)

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.02s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x000000
avrdude: Yikes!  Invalid device signature.
         Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
         this check.


avrdude done.  Thank you.```
````

Comment: I don't use this software, but Vtarget= 0.0V is an indication there's no power supply on the target chip in other programming software that I do use. With no power supply, it's not going to return a valid device signature.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: but the board has a power led that is shining, the ICSP header gets 5V from the Arduino (or I supposed it had)

Comment: i just tested the same fuse dump with another Uno as target and I get the values with the same Vtarget=0V

Comment: it's possible (by writing fuse bits) to put AVR flash parts into a state that can only be reset by the use of a 12V programmer (a parallel programmer for the parts with 16 or more pins)