# Mega2560 in circuit high voltage serial programming

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, atmel

Following my [other question on a bricked Mega2560](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/498884/bricked-mega2560-avrdude-gets-only-zeroes) I discovered that I probably locked-out myself with improper fuses values, and that high voltage programming could be the way to recover a working ICSP.

Following the datasheet of Mega2560, at § 28.5.2 "Scanning the RESET Pin", it is stated that applying 12V to the reset pin can enter the programming mode. But it is also talking of "parallel programming", and the operation mode is not detailed (or is it?).

My hope would be to use serial programming using the pins that are currently soldered to the ICSP port (MOSI/MISO/SCK/RESET/5V/GND), because the chip is a 100 pins TQFP form factor surface mounted, and it is very unlicky that I could unsolder / solder back the chip to my board, even if I do have a hot air soldering station.

The chip in-situ:
[image: creality v2.2]
I have found several posts and layouts for high voltage programming, often based on Uno or Mega arduinos, and always targeting DIP form factors AVRs like ATTinys. None was about Mega2560 as a target, and none is about in-site reprogramming.

Can someone confirm or infirm my hopes about the resurrection of my 3D printer?

Comment: Are you using the development board Mega2560, your own custom built board or only a single chip? Is your arduino IDE detecting the board?

Comment: @CFCBazarcom: the chip is soldered on a 3D printer mainboard, and the arduino IDE is only detecting the onboard FTDI usb port.

Comment: Its your own board? You created it, you did not buy it ready? Can you please provide the circuit?

Comment: @CFCBazarcomno it is the stock board that comes with the printer. I don't have the circuit, but was told it is based on the open-source RAMPS 1.4 (https://reprap.org/wiki/RAMPS_1.4) i do not see the usb FTDI chip on it though. An I noticed the RESET ICSP pin is shared between the mega and that R3 resistor.

Comment: If you have uunnnsoldered something, please resolder it. The ICSP in circuit serial programming works with low voltages. If you have burned the MCU, you need to replace it. If you have burned something else, you need to figure out what it is.

Comment: @CFCBazarcom but whatever i am trying to read from the chip (signature, fuses, flash) i now always get zeroes. Sign i may have disabled ICSP?

Comment: ICSP can not be disabled by software on this chip. It's a part of the bootloader and unless the chip is burned or the bootloader damaged, it will work. It's also possible that you have been cutting traces, especially on the reset pin and that your ICSP pins are not connected properly.